# Bootstrap 3.0.x - How to unconstrain input-group input width when using glyphicons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Not sure if this is a feature or a bug...

There has been a change in behaviour with `input-groups` using `glyphicons` between **bootstrap-3.0.0** and **bootstrap-3.0.1 and above**.

Starting from bootstrap-3.0.1, adding a `glyphicon` to an `input-group` causes the `input` width to be constrained.

I have two `input-groups`: one with a `glyphicon-user`, the other with an ascii `@` sign.

**New behaviour:**

As can be seen from the image below, with **bootstrap-3.0.1 and above**, the width of the  `input-group` with a `glyphicon-user` is constrained, while the one with an `@` sign is not.

[image: bootstrap-3 0 3]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevelorimer/va9Mk/1/) of the above issue with *bootstrap-3.0.3* (behaviour is the same with *3.0.1* and *3.0.2*)

**Old behaviour:**

On the other hand, as can be seen from the image below, the previous behaviour with **bootstrap-3.0.0** meant the width of the  `input-group` with a `glyphicon-user` was not constrained, thereby matching the one with an `@` sign.

[image: bootstrap-3 0 0]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevelorimer/6WGV8/1/) of the above with *bootstrap-3.0.0*

**Question:**

How can I get the *bootstrap-3.0.0* behaviour (unconstrained input-groups when using glyphicons)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Glyphicon classes cannot be used with any other classes.**

So by separating the `input-group-addon` class and `glyphicon` class into their own `spans`, it is easily fixed and yields correct results:

```
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
</span>
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stevelorimer/va9Mk/11/)**

[image]

The documentation even says so in a **big red warning!** :(

> **Don't mix with other components**
>
> *Icon classes cannot be combined with other elements. They are designed to be standalone elements.*

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be using a CSS selector `:empty` to set a width of 1em on the `.glypicon` which is overriding the default width of 1%.  I'm not sure why it's affecting it so much, I think it's affecting the table layout somehow.

Anyway, you can fix it 2 ways.

Override that `:empty` styling for items that are form addons:

```
.input-group-addon.glyphicon:empty {
  width: 1%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/va9Mk/3/)**

OR

Set the parent (that has the `display: table`) to be 100% wide:

```
.input-group {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/va9Mk/4/)**

Comment: Turns out I didn't rtfm properly! From the docs: **Don't mix with other components**
Icon classes cannot be combined with other elements. They are designed to be standalone elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem except withou using glyphicon or any input-group-addon.

When I have the following code in a page and I refresh the page non stop I can see the middle textbox trying to expand (flicker). Same behaviour if I remove the input-group.

```
<fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                <input type="email"
                    class="form-control"                            
                    placeholder="Email address"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" 
                    class="form-control"                            
                    placeholder="Full name"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                <input type="email"
                    class="form-control"                            
                    placeholder="Email address"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

For me it's all about the type used, if I set the type to text or password the width is restraint to it's original size. I have tried with Bootstrap 3.0.0 and 3.1.0. This behaviour happen on Chrome 34.0.1847 and Firefox 21.0 as well.