# How are `display: table-cell` widths calculated?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

This question comes out of [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129300/bootstrap-3-0-x-how-to-unconstrain-input-group-input-width-when-using-glyphico/21129530#21129530) which I provided a solution to, but couldn't provide an explanation as to why.

I've stripped their fiddle right down to the bare bones and have the following HTML / CSS:

```
<div class="table">
  <span class="cell-1">cell 1</span>
  <span class="cell-2">cell 2</span>
</div>

.table {
  display: table;
}

.cell-1, .cell-2 {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.cell-1 {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  width: 1%; /* *** FOCUS HERE *** */
}

.cell-2 {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

Only `.cell-1` has a width and that is 1%. **[This is the result (fiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/va9Mk/6/)**:

[image]

If I then increase the width of `.cell-1` to a value where it is wider than it's content, say 10% (I think that's the pattern anyway) then second cell will become narrower.  Why?  Where does that width come from?
**[This is the result (fiddle link).](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/va9Mk/9/)**

[image]

If I then take the second example, but add `width: 100%` to the `.table` then it goes back to 100% again.  **[Here's the result of that (fiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/va9Mk/10/)**.

I'm sure there's a logical explanation but I'm just not seeing it.  Anyone?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the result of the automatic table layout algorithm as implemented by the browser. This can vary across browsers because [the CSS2.1 spec doesn't specify all auto layout behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout), but it does outline an algorithm commonly used by browsers with HTML tables, because the CSS table model is based on the HTML table model for the most part.

In general, if the table doesn't have a specified width (i.e. it uses the default `auto`), then the cell with the percentage width is as wide as required by its contents, and no more. That calculated width (together with any other widths specified on other cells) is then used as the percentage to find the maximum width of the entire table, and the rest of the columns are resized accordingly. Note that the table can still be constrained by its containing block (in your example, it's the initial containing block established by the result pane).

On my PC running Firefox, `.cell-1` has a computed width of 33 pixels. When you specify its width as 1%, the maximum width that the table will have is 3300 pixels (33 × 100 = 3300). You would need a very large screen to see this in your example, so [I removed the padding which drastically reduces the width of `.cell-1` to 9 pixels and thus the maximum table width to 900 pixels](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/va9Mk/12). If you resize the preview pane to greater than 900 pixels, you will see that the table stops growing at that point.

When you increase the width of `.cell-1` to 10%, the same 33 pixels now becomes 10% of the maximum width of the table. In turn, the maximum table width becomes 330 pixels (which is in fact 10% of 3300 pixels, because 100 ÷ 10 = 10).

The moment you specify the width of `.table` as 100%, the table is sized according to its containing block. In your case, that just means stretching it to the full width of the result pane. `.cell-1` still has to obey its `width: 10%` declaration, so it stretches to 10% of the width of the table since the content doesn't require anything wider. If you resize the result pane to a very narrow width, you'll see that `.cell-1` shrinks along with the table, but not past its minimum content width.

Answer (score 1):

By default, CSS `tables` have 3 components in lieu of HTML `tables`

- `display:table`

  by default, this will take the content width unless the UA styles override it with the `width: xx%` property
- `display:table-row`

  this attribute has got no height for itself and only follows the dimesnion of the `td`, i.e., table-cell in it.
- `display:table-cell`

  like `display:table`, it also takes the width of its parent, .i.e., `table` and is divided equally in terms of width among its siblings. for eg., if you have 200px wide table with 5 cells (*and none of them have width defined manually*), all the `table-cell` would take equal `px` amongst them....`40px` each!!

Comment: this solution comes as a part of personal coding as no specs mention the layout pattern for CSS tables!! :)