# How to get overflow:auto behavior with HTML table

Tags: html, css, overflow

Given a `<table>` with one or many `<td>`'s with text that is wider than the parent `<div>`, is there a way to make the table scroll without making the parent `<div>` use `overflow:auto`, and still have the table retain 100% width?

I'm hoping for a CSS solution I can apply to ONLY the `<table>` element (or its children).

Example: [See JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94g53edb/2/).

CSS:

```
<style>
#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    /* looking for solution that doesn't use overflow auto here */
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Table should scroll, but not this text.</p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>..</td>
                <td>..</td>
                <td>....................................................................................</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>..</td>
                <td>..</td>
                <td>..</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Not modifying the parent `div` is important in my project because `<table>`'s are in a `<div>` with a bunch of other content that I do not want to scroll with it. While I could add a wrapper `<div>` to all tables in my project, I would also have to rewrite a JavaScript plugin (has to do with paging), which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overflow: scroll` on the table itself if you make it display as block:

```
table {
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**Edit:**
As the comments below suggest, use `td { width: 1%; }` as a somewhat-messy way to get the table to still be 100% width if the content is narrower than the wrapper.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/94g53edb/12/

Comment: This makes the table lose its 100% width if the content is shorter. I am applying the style to a variety of tables so some will have long content and others short. See http://jsfiddle.net/94g53edb/7/

Comment: @Justin you could add `td { width: 100%; }` but that will expand just the first td.

Comment: @Justin `td { width: 1%; }` seems to make the trick. At least in Firefox.

Comment: It works for me on Chrome but I'm squemish to use a hack like that without knowing why it works. Do you know what's happening to make it stretch with a 1% width?

Comment: @Justin I used it like a hack several times, here's an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130221/how-are-display-table-cell-widths-calculated

Comment: I can't post more than two links since my rep is still too low, so here are the fiddles for narrow and wide content demos using `td { width: 1%; }`:

Comment: I don't think there is a solution that doesn't require any extra markup and still works in obsolete browsers. This works in all the modern browsers I've tested.

Comment: Fair enough. IE 10+ works with the 1% hack. I'll accept your answer tomorrow if I don't get any better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am just a newbie in css and html, but if I can give my opinion, so there will be two ways in achieving that:

1. You can set the `<p>` to the fixed position,

or

1. You can create another wrapper for the table.

:)

Comment: Since the content is variable inside the wrapper, setting it to fixed position would not be a reliable solution. Your second answer is what I said I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm adding a second answer because the comments on my first answer are going in a different direction than my new answer, and I don't want to derail that train]

Set the table to `display: block` and `overflow: scroll`, and give each of the cells a `min-width` (in pixels) to make up 100% of the container's width.

Here's what it looks like with table content less than the container width: http://jsfiddle.net/94g53edb/8/

Because the cells have only a min-width and not a fixed width, they can expand as needed, pushing the table to greater than the width of the container, and the table will scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/94g53edb/9/

Comment: I like the concept but the `<td>` widths are all variable.