# Trying to shrink div with max-width to children width, but it is the max-width value

Tags: html, css

I have three divs vertically aligned side by side. The first div has a max width but for some reason that div is larger than the content. It is the width set for max-width. I would like names to wrap in a way that fits in the max-width and then for the div to shrink to whatever the width the children dictate.

The content is generated dynamically so I do not want to set widths for any div. The only thing I want to set is the max-width of the wrapper of all the names.

It currently looks like the example in the top image - I would like it to look like the example in the bottom:

[image: example]

Here is an example in Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYPRLX

```
<div id="exhibition_title_wrapper">
<div id="exhibition_title_name">
<div class="artist_name">Steve Greenberg</div>,
<div class="artist_name">Sarah Thompson</div>,
<div class="artist_name">Bill Bradbury</div>,
<div class="artist_name">Tom Rogers</div>,
<div class="artist_name">Nicole Haight</div> 
<div class="artist_name">Barney Franklin</div>,
<div class="artist_name">Todd Franklin</div> 
</div>
<div id="slash"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/r1gx8okp7/slash.png"></div>
<div id="exhibition_title_right">
<div id="exhibition_title_title">Expo 3000</div>
<div id="exhibition_title_date">September 1-20, 2017</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS

```
#exhibition_title_wrapper {display:block;}
#exhibition_title_name {display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle; max-width:300px;}
.artist_name {display: inline-block;}
#slash {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0 10px;}
#exhibition_title_right {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
#exhibition_title_title {display:}
#exhibition_title_date {display:}
```

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Not possible with CSS (AFAIK)...that's just the way the line-box and box model work.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596213/shrink-div-to-text-thats-wrapped-to-its-max-width?rq=1

Comment: Hm, I guess [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbEpGZ) won't work?

Comment: That looks like it may work! What exactly is it doing? Putting two names and then a line break?

Comment: @JackCash Yes, that's what it does.